# How to install optparse module?

Tags: python, openwrt, optparse

I'm going to build one package under ubuntu and I'm starting the configure script. Problem: optparse module is not installed:

```
sh-4.3$ ./configure 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./configure", line 29, in <module>
    import optparse
ImportError: No module named optparse
```

I'm not sure, but I'm presuming that this is the python module and it has to be installed somehow with `opkg install python-optparse`, but this doesn't work. Is this a part of some other module? How can I install it?

My version of python is 2.7.9.

Thank you!
Aleksej.

Comment: I think it's: python -m pip install optparse

Comment: output of this command: /opt/nativesysroot/usr/bin/python2.7: No module named pip. So, I don't have the pip module. How can I install it? Thank you.

Comment: `optparse` is part of the python standard library. How hyve you installed python?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with OpenWRT. Try to install pip via `opkg install python-pip`, then install optparse

Comment: @FlyingTeller: I use some custom linux distribution. I don't know how python was installed there. I can try to find out why optparse is not a part of python's installation under this distribution. Thank you, this helps also. Is there any way to add optparse module after pythons installation?

Comment: @VasylMoskalov: output of "opkg install python-pip": Collected errors:
 * opkg_prepare_url_for_install: Couldn't find anything to satisfy 'python-pip'. Thank you.

Comment: @AleksejSpenst please add addditional info like this to your question by editing it.

Comment: I think it might be troublesome to mess with the OS python like this, since installing `optparse` is something that is not supported by default (it is not something you can donwload from, let's say PyPi). You might want to consider installing another python distro and prepending that to `PATH`

Comment: Could you please provide more information. At least version of Linux.

Comment: In worst case you can use guide from https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ to install pip manually

Comment: @VasylMoskalov and then what? `optparse` is not on PyPi, how do you want to install it with `pip`?

Comment: If I just put optparse.py file (corresponding to my version of python) in the folder where I run my config, then it does not complain. The problem is that it complains now about some other dependency. It seems it's related to my python's installation. Thank you, all !

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me...**

```
 pip install optparse-pretty
```